# How to convert string to datetime using Convert.ChangeType not considering timezone

Tags: c#

This code adds time zone to DateTime, in the real scenario this code is inside a generic function to convert strings to various types. So I need a generic code to work to all types:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.MinValue;
string s = "2006-10-31T11:17:50Z";
d = (DateTime)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(DateTime),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

On my PC with +1 timezone `d` is:
{31/10/2006 12:17:50}

Is there a way to ignore the time zone?

I can't use `DateTime.Parse` nor `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: Why can't you use DateTime.Parse?

Comment: If I understand your question: you mean you want variable "d" to hold any data type. Am I right?

Comment: You should not ignore TimeZone.  The DateTime will be stored incorrectly.  A Datetime is stored in the computer in UTF time.  The Net library uses the timezone settings in your computer to convert the local time to UTF.  When data is collected in a different timezone from your computer you MUST use the time zone to store the data correctly.

Comment: the code resides inside a funciton, that function get as input an object, a list of string values and a list of properties, first value -> first property, second value -> second property.... Convert.ChangeType need to assing the string value to corresponding object's property. void SetPropValue(object oSource, string PropName, object PropValue, string Info)

Comment: `public void SetPropValue(object oSource, string PropName, object PropValue)
{
 PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo = oSource.GetType().GetProperty(PropName);
 oPropertyInfo.SetValue(oSource, Convert.ChangeType(PropValue, oPropertyInfo.PropertyType), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}`

Comment: @FDB why not using generics?

Comment: @Kryptos can u give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you receive the type you want to convert into as a parameter and that's why you can't use DateTime.Parse...
But can you at least test for the type ? something like that is not the prettiest but should work:

```
var s = "2006-10-31T11:17:50Z";
var t = typeof(DateTime);
var d = Convert.ChangeType(s, t, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if (t == typeof(DateTime))
   d = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc((DateTime)d);

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
```

Output

```
10/31/2006 11:17:50 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

Using generics (you can adapt to fit your needs):

```
public TDest ConvertValue<TSrc, TDest>(TSrc src, Func<TDest, TDest> adapter = null)
{
    var converted = Convert.ChangeType(src, typeof(TDest), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (adapter == null)
    {
        adapter = GetDefaultAdapter<TDest>();
    }
    return adapter(converted);
}

private static readonly Hashtable DefaultAdapters = InitializeAdapters();
private static Hashtable InitializeAdapters()
{
    var hashtable = new Hashtable
    {
        {typeof (DateTime).Name, (Func<DateTime, DateTime>)(t => DateTime.SpecifyKind(t, t.ToUniversalTime())},
    };

    return hashtable;
}

public static Func<T, T> GetDefaultAdapter<T>()
{
    Func<T, T> ret = f => f;
    if (DefaultAdapters.ContainsKey(typeof(T).Name))
    {
        ret = (Func<T, T>)DefaultAdapters[typeof(T).Name];
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the time difference between your time zone and the target time zone you can use [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) to include the said difference.